# I got some incorrect datetime format, and I want to convert it to correct format using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the input data  2019-09-06 00:00:1567702800
I have tried a lot of method to change it to YYYY-MM-DD format but it doesn't work, because of this part "00:00:1567702800" does not the correct format. It should be 00:00:15.67702800. How can I change the format from 00:00:1567702800   to 00:00:15.67702800?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that your data looks something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'my_date':['2019-09-06 00:00:1567702800']})

print(df)

>                        my_date
> 0  2019-09-06 00:00:1567702800
```

If I understand correctly, you want to convert this date to `yyyy-mm-dd` format. If this is so, then you can ignore everything that goes after the days in each string and parse the remaining characters:

```py
# Get the first 10 characters of each string
df['parsed_date'] = df['my_date'].str[:10], format='%Y-%m-%d')

# Parse string with corresponding format
df['parsed_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['parsed_date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly with my data set. Thank you so much for sharing this knowledge

Comment: Happy to help dude! I edited my answer to explain what I'm doing in each step.

Answer (score 1):

I assume someone will have a better answer but one way would be:

```
s = "2019-09-06 00:00:1567702800"    
s = ''.join([s[:19],".",s[19:]])
```

which could be applied on a pandas series using:

```
df[col].astype(str).apply(lambda x: ''.join([x[:19], ".", x[19:]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to parse the date using format string `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%f'` (second followed immediately by microsecond).  Then after the date is successfully parsed, format the date using [`dt.strftime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) with format string only `'%Y-%m-%d'`:

```
df['out_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['in_date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%f').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'in_date':['2019-09-06 00:00:1567702800']})
df['out_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['in_date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%f').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

print(df)

                       in_date    out_date
0  2019-09-06 00:00:1567702800  2019-09-06
```

Here, the data type of `out_date` is string.  If you want to keep the `out_date` as `datetime64` data type with only down to date without the hours till microseconds, you can use [`dt.normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html)

```
df['out_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['in_date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%f').dt.normalize()
```

```
df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------    --------------  -----         
 0   in_date   1 non-null      object        
 1   out_date  1 non-null      datetime64[ns]         <=== datetime64 format
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(1)
memory usage: 144.0+ bytes
```